# Phonegap failed to find ANDROID_HOME environment variable on Ubuntu

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, environment-variables, phonegap-cli

I followed up this [Tutorial](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu/) to install phonegap on Ubuntu, everything worked just fine I was even able to run the simulator .

But when I was trying to run my phonegap project on it I got this error :

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova emulate android'...
cp: no such file or directory: /home/abdessalem/Documents/test/icon.png


Running command: /home/abdessalem/Documents/test/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator

ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Error: /home/abdessalem/Documents/test/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
```

As the article saying I add my enviroment variable in `~/.profile`

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to

```
source ~/.profile
```

or logout and then back in

or you can simply enter the export commands before trying the cordova command

make sure the environment variables point to the correct locations in your system

Comment: Same problem, nothing is changed

Comment: Marox Tn what' the output of `which android`

Comment: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android

Comment: Is it what its suppose to be ?

Comment: The path seems correct. What's the output of `printenv | grep ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux

Comment: Did you try searching for "Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable" There seem to be several related issues listes in stackoverflow